# Usage of \greadlist* from package 'listofitems'

Tags: macros, packages, itemize, expansion, listofitems

I'm trying to define a *LIST* using *\greadlist* from the *listofitems* package. I would like to give a dynamic name to that list, something like *LISTN*, where *N* depends on a counter.

I tried something like

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{listofitems}

\begin{document}
\newcounter{num}\setcounter{num}{1}
\setsepchar{,}
\greadlist*{\expandafter\noexpand\csname LIST\roman{num}\endcsname}{a,b,c}
\end{document}
```

But this just make LaTeX not stop running...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expand the `\csname` *before* invoking the `\greadlist`.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{listofitems}

\begin{document}
\newcounter{num}\setcounter{num}{4}
\setsepchar{,}
\expandafter\greadlist\expandafter*\csname 
  LIST\roman{num}\endcsname{a,b,c}

\LISTiv[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can define your own variation of the commands.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{listofitems}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\readnamedlist}{smm}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {\exp_args:NNc \readlist*{#2}{#3}} % * variant
   {\exp_args:Nc \readlist{#2}{#3}}
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\greadnamedlist}{smm}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {\exp_args:NNc \greadlist*{#2}{#3}} % *-variant
   {\exp_args:Nc \greadlist{#2}{#3}}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\newcounter{num}\setcounter{num}{1}
\setsepchar{,}

\greadnamedlist*{LIST\roman{num}}{a,b,c}

\LISTi[1],\LISTi[2],\LISTi[3]

\stepcounter{num}

\readnamedlist{LIST\roman{num}}{d,e,f}

\LISTii[1],\LISTii[2],\LISTii[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

What does `\exp_args:Nc` do? It jumps over the next token and applies `\csname...\endcsname` to the contents of the following braced group. Similarly `\exp_args:NNc` that jumps over two tokens.

If you prefer a “classical” implementation, here's an argument reversing procedure.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{listofitems}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\readnamedlist}{%
  \@ifstar{\@readnamedlist{\readlist*}}{\@readnamedlist{\readlist}}%
}
\newcommand{\greadnamedlist}{%
  \@ifstar{\@readnamedlist{\greadlist*}}{\@readnamedlist{\greadlist}}%
}
\newcommand{\@readnamedlist}[2]{%
  \expandafter\@@readnamedlist\csname #2\endcsname{#1}%
}
\newcommand{\@@readnamedlist}[2]{#2#1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\newcounter{num}\setcounter{num}{1}
\setsepchar{,}

\greadnamedlist*{LIST\roman{num}}{a,b,c}

\LISTi[1],\LISTi[2],\LISTi[3]

\stepcounter{num}

\readnamedlist{LIST\roman{num}}{d,e,f}

\LISTii[1],\LISTii[2],\LISTii[3]

\end{document}
```

Comment: @UlrichDiez Maybe, but I find this clearer and more in line with `expl3` guidelines.

Answer (score 2):

I think those days expl3-solutions are state of the art, so I'd in any case prefer egreg's solution.

The following is just for exhibiting the technique of exchanging arguments after expansion:

```latex
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{listofitems}

\newcommand\PassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}%

\begin{document}
\newcounter{num}\setcounter{num}{1}
\setsepchar{,}
\expandafter\PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\csname LIST\roman{num}\endcsname}{\greadlist*}{a,b,c}
\end{document}
```

Alternatively a macro
`\CsNameToCsToken⟨stuff not in braces⟩{NameOfCs}`
→
`⟨stuff not in braces⟩\NameOfCs`
can help avoiding/hiding `\expandafter...\csname..\endcsname`-orgies:

```latex
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{listofitems}

%%===============================================================================
%% Obtain control sequence token from name of control sequence token:
%%===============================================================================
%% \CsNameToCsToken<stuff not in braces>{NameOfCs}
%% ->  <stuff not in braces>\NameOfCs
%% (<stuff not in braces> may be empty.)
\csname @ifdefinable\endcsname\CsNameToCsToken{%
  \long\def\CsNameToCsToken#1#{\InnerCsNameToCsToken{#1}}%
}%
\newcommand\InnerCsNameToCsToken[2]{%
  \expandafter\exchange\expandafter{\csname#2\endcsname}{#1}%
}%
\newcommand\exchange[2]{#2#1}%
%%===============================================================================

\begin{document}
\newcounter{num}\setcounter{num}{1}
\setsepchar{,}
\CsNameToCsToken\greadlist*{LIST\roman{num}}{a,b,c}
\end{document}
```

(If it were implemented there, in expl3 the name of `\CsNameToCsToken` would probably be something like `\exp_args:wc` or whatever argument-type you use instead of `w` for an argument which must not be nested in braces but is delimited by a left brace `{`.)